# Socket IO emit events twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

**Situation:**

I'm setting up an express server with socket.io and a client using ReactJS. This is my server:

```
//... another requirement
const socket = require("./socket");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//... some parsers ...

routes(app);
socket(server);

server.listen(port);
console.log("Server started on: " + port);
```

And this is my socket:

```
const socketIO = require("socket.io");

const socket = server => {
  const io = socketIO(server);
  const chat = io.of("/chat");
  chat.on("connection", client => {
    console.log("User started chat!");
    client.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("User left chat!");
    });

    client.on("sendMessage", msg => {
      const { id, text } = msg;
      console.log(id + " says: " + text);
      client.broadcast.emit("incomingMessage", {
        //... response data
      });
    });
  });
};
```

In the client, the Chat Page component will handle sending message to socket and receiving message from socket:

```
//_ChatBox in Chat Page
const _ChatBox = (/*props*/) => {
  const chat = io("http://localhost" + ":3000/chat");

  chat.on("incomingMessage", message => {
    console.log("Receive message");
    //...handle income message
  });

  const sendMessageToSocket = (data) => {
    chat.emit("sendMessage", data);
  };

  return ( /*JSX*/);
};
```

**Problem:**

Everytime a user accesses Chat Page, socket will receive connect event and log `User started chat!` to console once, but actually, it has logged twice, that means the socket has handled the connect event twice.

And when _ChatBox receives message, it will log `Receive message` and display that message, but what it has done is log that twice and display the message twice, that also means the socket has emitted the incomeMessage event twice.

**What i want:** I want the socket only handles those events once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like your component is rendering twice, so calling `const chat = io("http://localhost" + ":3000/chat");` twice, giving two connection messages.

You can use a [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to only connect on the first render. Passing in an empty array as the second argument means the effect will only be called once:

```
const _ChatBox = (/*props*/) => {

  useEffect(()=>{
     const chat = io("http://localhost" + ":3000/chat");

    chat.on("incomingMessage", message => {
      console.log("Receive message");
      //...handle income message
     });

     const sendMessageToSocket = (data) => {
      chat.emit("sendMessage", data);
     };
   }, []);


  return ( /*JSX*/);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand why the component is rendered twice!

Comment: React renders the component twice due to StrictMode. This mode checks if there are any unwanted side-effects in all components by basically shaking it hard. If the useEffect causes different behaviour the second mount, there's something wrong which would cause problems in a production application.

Luckily there is no double render (no strictmode) in a production app. This is purely React helping you prevent potential problems when your useEffects() become more complex or even problematic.

Answer (score 2):

**Create socket inside index.js file and pass as a prop to the root app component like this :-**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client"
var socket = socketIOClient('http://localhost:9000');
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <App socket={socket} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Now Use This socket to emit events like this:-**

```
import React from "react"
import './App.css';
class App extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.socket.emit('test')
}
render() {
  return (
     <div>
        hello
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by writing inside my functional component
a useEffect that opens socket onMount (and onUpdate) but CLOSES SOCKET ON UNMOUNT.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const socket = io("http://localhost:3000")
    socket.on(userId, (arg) => {
        //stuff
    }); 
    return () => socket.emit('end'); //Close socket on UNMOUNT
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it.

```
 return() => {
     socket.off("whatever_you_named").off();
 }
```

As you see [here](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-hooks), you have to use the `useEffect` function that React is providing. Next, you have to attach the below code inside of your `useEffect` function to prevent receiving the same message twice. If you have 4 listening methods, you would have to attach that codes 4 times to prevent that problem for each method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions here already that contain *parts* of a complete answer and while this answer may already be available in pieces I think it is helpful to have it all in one place.

As others have said, you need to turn your listener on inside of a `useEffect` hook but *also* to include a `return` statement in which your listener is turned off. This way if/when the component reloads it doesn't add an additional instance of the listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('event-name', eventHandlingFunction);

  return () => {
    socket.off('event-name', eventHandlingFunction);
  };
}, [eventHandlingFunction]);
```

Incidentally you can also use the above structure for `socket.onAny` and `socket.offAny`, though you would, of course, not include the name of a single event socket was listening for.

Answer (score 0):

Add websocket.off("eventname") in return of useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
   ws.on("room-created", enterRoom);

   return () => {
     ws.off("room-created");
   };
 }, []);
```